# Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated after NPM

Tags: npm

after i execute npm install npm@latest -g,
i can not use another npm command
it just say

```html
(node:1948) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

here is the log after install and the error

[image]

Comment: Please, post the error as message. Nothing here needs it as a screenshot. It can be seen that you use Node 8. It's ancient. That's the problem.